# Displaying images without a margin in an iframe with Firefox and IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, iframe

I'm working on a project that uses an iframe to display images. The problem I've encountered is that while Chrome (version 41) displays the images without any margin Firefox (version 37) and IE (version 11) ignore the 0px margin styling applied to body tags. This is observable by examining the iframe element.

[Here](http://courierinvoice.ddns.net) is my test page.

Is there a way to fix this or will I have to resort to javascript to accomplish what should be a very simple thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by Drasill [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011230/how-can-i-remove-extra-margin-from-inside-an-iframe?rq=1). The attributes marginheight="0" and marginwidth="0" remedied the situation. However, they have to be applied inline. Including them in the style sheet didn't have any effect.