# There is mysterious grey padding with a border around my iframe youtube embedded videos

Tags: html, css, iframe

I've been looking everywhere on the web for a solution but nobody else has ran into the same issue as me. I am using iFrame and jquery.oembed to embed a youtube video on my site. But there is this padding on the right side of the video and it has a border on the right side as well. I tried all of the various border removal techniques but this seems to be a padding issue. The grey padding seems to be a part of the iframe window. Has anyone else ever had this issue? I've tried everything from removing the border to setting the padding and margins to 0 but the right padding and grey background are still there.

Comment: post a demo please

Comment: Have you tried `frameborder="0"` to remove the border? [More info](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_frameborder.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys I found the answer on another thread. Here is the link incase anyone else comes across this issue.

[How can I remove extra margin from INSIDE an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011230/how-can-i-remove-extra-margin-from-inside-an-iframe)

This is what I had to add to my

```
<iframe src="..."
 marginwidth="0"
 marginheight="0"
 hspace="0"
 vspace="0"
 frameborder="0"
 scrolling="no"></iframe>
```